# YAML pipeline unable to parse input parameter with special characters to a Python task

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

How do I escape/handle parentheses/arbitrary inputs with special characters such as the one I have shown below so that my python code gets the proper string argument?

I have a YAML pipeline and it takes an input parameter as a string from the user, and provides that string as an argument to a Python task:

```
   - name: Name
     displayName: Username
     type: string
     default: "-"

   - task: PythonScript@0
     displayName: 'Python task'
     inputs:
       scriptPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/x/y.py
       arguments: ' -Name "${{parameters.Name}}" '
       workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/x'
```

This input parameters works fine for alphanumeric characters, but when I input a string that has opening and closing round brackets (such as Foo(Bar)), the Python YAML task prints an error:

> /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Please note that the above error appears in the pipeline logs before the Python script execution even begins

**Success input string**: FooBar

**Failure input string**: Foo(Bar)

How do I handle this so that my Python script gets the correct string?

Python script:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test")
parser.add_argument("-Name")

args = parser.parse_args()

user_name= args.Name
```

Edit: Added more clarity, and added Python script

Comment: ould you share with us ur script ?

Comment: @Thomas I have updated my description with my script, but the error I am seeing appears in the pipeline logs - before the script execution even begins

Comment: How are you passing in `Foo(Bar)`, ie `parameters.name`? Seems like you need to escape it there

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Foo(Bar) is passed as a user input from the pipeline. It is a parameter that will take any string value. I'm accessing that param value as `' -Name "${{parameters.Name}}" '`

Comment: I understand that, but can you give an example of the user input syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.
I wrapped my input parameter with double quotes and now I am able to take input strings with special characters.
I output pipeline variable from my Python script for the next task, but due to the special character, I used to get this error.